# Set environment variable befare launching debug process by IDA

Tags: python, x86, 64-bit, ida

I want to add environment variables before launching my python script by IDA to debug a library.

I set up `Process Options` in Debugger menu and set Application to x86 python. But it seems there is no environment variable options.

Is there any way to do so?

IDA Pro 7.5 is x64 application and it uses x64 python. But I want to debug x86 python so I need to change `PYTHONHOME` before launching python process.

I tried to use bat file to do it but it launched another process. So it didn't work.

[Envirionment]

- Windows 10

Comment: I decided adding paths to `sys.path` from x86 python side every time.

Answer (score 0):

If it is remote debugging, add the required environment variables when the mac_server or linux_server starts